# How To Install GCC 7.1 and GDB 7.12.1 Ubuntu 16.04 from sources?

Tags: gcc, gdb, ubuntu-16.04

Since I know these versions doesn't come installed on Ubuntu 16.04, I've got the packages from their website. How can I install it? I've tried a bunch of online tutorials and none of them seem to work.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I do

Comment: `sudo apt-get build-dep gdb` to install libraries. Then `cd` to gdb source directory extracted from the tar file. `./configure` then `make` then `sudo make install` will install in various directories under `/usr/local`. The new gdb will then be `/usr/local/bin/gdb`. To install elsewhere, give `--prefix=/yourdesiredpathname` argument to `./configure`. It's not recommended to install with a prefix of `/usr` since that will overwrite the default gdb and it'll get overwritten when Ubuntu issues an update for their gdb.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick the first command is not working it says something about adding sources

Comment: Can you paste the error messages?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick "E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list"

Comment: Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and uncomment all the `# deb-src` lines, then run `sudo apt-get update`, then try the first apt-get command again.

Comment: Hello world.  Thanks for that :)

Comment: Thanks, Mark's comment should be the answer instead of a comment